# Renaming custom object referenced in Apex class

Tags: custom-object

Can somebody please suggest me what is the best way i can rename custom object name when it is referenced in class and triggers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The API Name? That's never easy. I typically have to comment out all the references to it in the code, change the name and then uncomment the code. You'll then have to redeploy all that code to your production org.

Comment: Salesforce is nice enough to stop you from destroying your code, not nice enough to refactor your code in real time.